# How to respond to a "we'll call you when the position opens" response, when you see the position opened?

Tags: communication, job-search

Alright, so here's my scenario.

I recently went through the application process at a company that I really would like to work for. It's a programming position, and I made it through their initial technical phone interview. I was also given a take home coding project. My first attempt on the coding project resulted in them passing on me. Over the following several months, I spent a lot of time learning how to make my submission better. Eventually, I re-contacted the employee at the company who interviewed me, and I asked if I could submit the project again. He allowed it and said that my 2nd submission looked much better. He said two other lead developers also liked the submission and said that I would be a candidate for a mid-level position.

This was awesome news, because that's what I was applying for and I've wanted to work there for a long time.

Unfortunately, he said that at that time they were only hiring senior developers. Since this 2nd submission of mine took place several months after my original submission, I understood his situation. He said he would email me when the position opens up again.

Well, fast forward a month and the position just became listed as open on their website. It's Wednesday today, and the position became open I believe on Monday. How should I proceed with this situation?

I'd like to email so that if he has happened to forget about me, then I will re-enter the picture and have a chance at the job. I don't mind waiting, but waiting could also mean I get passed on because I didn't act on it. At the same time though, I don't want to somehow sound like I didn't believe that he'd contact me when the position opens, or come off as somehow being too aggressive in seeking the position.

What do you all think? If I do email him, how should I word that? Or should I just wait and hope that he has not forgotten me.

Comment: If it's been a month since you last contacted him, you are not being too aggressive. I think you could easily say something like, "I see the position we talked about just opened up on your website. I hope I'm not jumping the gun, but I wanted to let you know I'm still very interested in working there." Or something like that.

Answer (score 20):

You should contact the employer, and tell them plainly that you saw that the position opened up and would still be interested in working for the company. It is not rude, or pushy, as it has been several months,so it would be understandable if they have forgotten about you. If nothing else, its showing that you are persistent and determined, character traits which I would hope they would admire as an employer.

Answer (score 6):

That's a difficult situation and one that I have faced a couple of times actually. What I would recommend is to still contact him first. He's probably very busy and shouldn't take it personally if you contact him ahead of time. Also consider that he may have seen thousands of resumes (depending on the size of the company) and he has just forgotten about you, meaning you should jog his memory.

Obviously this wording can change, but you can perhaps figure out a way to phrase it nicely such as, "If I seem persistent in contacting you, it's because I feel this would be a great opportunity and don't want to let it pass by". Basically you're re-routing the potential thought that you're being pushy, into you being very passionate about the job.

Every time I have been in this situation and contacted the recruiter before they contacted me back, I was just seen as a "go-getter" or "very passionate about the job".